# Flatten object with custom keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript, flatten

I want to flat object and transform returned values as a type.

Eg:

```
const myObject = {
  names: {
    title: 'red',
    subtitle: 'green'
  },
}
const returned = [...Object.values(flatten(myObject))] as const
// returns ['red', 'green']
type Type = typeof returned[number]
```

returned variable is ['red', 'green'] now

Type should be 'red | 'green', but now is an array of string, because typeof returned is string[].
I want to use this type to type prop for my component:

```
<Component name="red" /> //is correct, but
<Component name=`something different than "red" or "green"` /> //is incorrect.
```

flatten function:

```
type FlattenedObject = { [x: string]: string }

export const flattenDaisyChain = (obj: any): FlattenedObject => {
  const result: FlattenedObject = {}

  const transform = (wrapper: FlattenedObject | string, p?: string) => {
    switch (typeof wrapper) {
      case 'object':
        p = p ? p + '.' : ''
        for (const item in wrapper) {
          transform(wrapper[item], p + item)
        }
        break
      default:
        if (p) {
          result[p] = wrapper
        }
        break
    }
  }

  transform(obj)

  return result
}
```

Comment: Please share full example. It is unable to reproduce

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, if you want to have any chance of the compiler realizing that `Type` is `"red" | "green"` as opposed to `string`, we have to make sure that `myObjct`'s type includes these [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The easy way to do that is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const myObject = {
  names: {
    title: 'red',
    subtitle: 'green'
  },
} as const;
```

---

Next, your `flatten()` function has a type that is only barely representable in TypeScript 4.1+.  I might write it like this, using an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919016/how-can-an-object-type-with-nested-subproperties-be-flattened):

```
type Flatten<T extends object> = object extends T ? object : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: (x: NonNullable<T[K]> extends infer V ? V extends object ?
        V extends readonly any[] ? Pick<T, K> : Flatten<V> extends infer FV ? ({
            [P in keyof FV as `${Extract<K, string | number>}.${Extract<P, string | number>}`]:
            FV[P] }) : never : Pick<T, K> : never
    ) => void } extends Record<keyof T, (y: infer O) => void> ?
    O extends infer U ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never : never

const flatten = <T extends object>(obj: T): Flatten<T> => { /* impl */ }
```

It uses [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), and [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to recursively walk down through all the properties and concatenate keys together with `.` in between.  I have no idea if this particular type function will work for all the use cases of `flatten()`, and I wouldn't dare to pretend that it doesn't have demons lurking in it.

---

If I use that signature, and call `flatten(myObject)` with the above `const`-asserted `myObject`, you get this:

```
const flattenedMyObject = flatten(myObject);
/* const flattenedMyObject: {
    readonly "names.title": "red";
    readonly "names.subtitle": "green";
} */
```

Hooray!  And this is enough information for `Type` to be `"red" | "green"`:

```
const returned = [...Object.values(flatten(myObject))] as const
type Type = typeof returned[number] // "red" | "green"
```

Also hooray.

---

I suppose if you don't really care about tracking the key names, you can simplify the `flatten()` type signature considerably by returning something with a [`string` index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
type DeepValueOf<T> = object extends T ? object :
    T extends object ? DeepValueOf<
        T[Extract<keyof T, T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown>]
    > : T

const flatten = <T extends object>(obj: T): { [k: string]: DeepValueOf<T> } => {
    /* impl */ }
```

which produces

```
const flattenedMyObject = flatten(myObject);
/* const flattenedMyObject: {
   [k: string]: "green" | "red";
 } */
```

and eventually

```
const returned = [...Object.values(flatten(myObject))] as const
type Type = typeof returned[number] // "red" | "green"
```

I'm less worried about `DeepValueOf` than I am about `Flatten`, but I would be surprised if there aren't some edge cases.  So you'd need to really test before using it in any sort of production code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAygFgIxIN4Ch8likAXATxmQDEAbEU0iYAHhSQgA8ngATKJAHsARgCsI8UgD4kAXiFiJpDt2b9USAPwLxkpAC48REiYDaAaSQBLYEgDWEcoIBmqALoBaTYYAUnQwBygsABAK609MK0EGwWbjJcPOo2zhAATkgAalpZKkkCIrrKmsYmZbmJagJpECC8wbTkSCDA5KZuOQAKVvB2bAA0SOYyhnQMPCyZCap8AinpSNTZ2j4E5eskpp3Wtg5OrkvNAgAGACS4AKLcaQikLOaDUKRpNgDmSAA+SMChYMLpUgAvgA6c5XZ63FidR7PN6fb6-f5pIHHNz6UobMpLLYdQEASgM3wgADcFoZur0BkMRkTSWkMSYCbIZMTBFZeEhAXkqkgAEoSQRpXgsPYuVCDHzkQzzDIAeSZLLZvBkJQ2su5sx2qQyAFUcrgkBYdvZHGLZWikLK4pzCcASWTaelCCZ4MEnkhnPRGMw5Eg2Br1IUlFIfIVDCg8aMvRMUDJmUYNq7gO6alBwqRDC0mvJcIDnesk+6IcnnIKwL6fAB3G4wKhpTOtQYwbxIJ4vYCvBUJzHEKCVqykeAACyQPgoVDF1ZAtfSBLWPbK8BAUGQAHIg5JV+iF5iYL699o9wBqJCr4Grwmr1cMnckUsZHyF5QDiDlmxIKcztJzm+3srFqB7zAKsazrUwXzANwmyQE8ILxX9bzzP9ymEGoQDsBCNl4CBnBAdNt2QkwrFcHwYB-QiNlTdNTBgDp5E-OtMIXJCKOIVDagwncWPKPMEIAoDQzEeCEJqUhQjSWwqNoUgMV4l03WUMByFlRQ9BzBDQEgKBDHnHtSAHaJDFXGpeFXfomN7UJhH00hDNPV4amYa8NkBcyTC5ZckCfABufNiCfD1o2YCBeAAWWU1TlHkT1xmYHwlJUoo8V8kwAHoACovIUwLYrtMKIqKHSRNqepgEaJAACJNOgYEbOiCrDAqkyKpS9Y0NK8qqvAGq02sgyIAayqHIgZgWtkpB0tSvysuTQRomBWhBFeHwYu9YB4oKpQ8WS6aAtE8S8t9UxgROxKlGBYkQFoUJoBWoL1oSyLto6TynwxcdkBQShkHkD6xX2iSQtMH4-nSDpUtSyrmvhCrhtGwhCF4-BqtgBBkAASVeYBBQgcxHAEAh3u+pAABERpgTIrpu2VnDYOMdCUAMBHYbQN2UAjynYSpNTZnIyYgCmqYgGnYnBG5JBFU1XBQQYuZmdR2oaJos3aHIQaRQlQmAOxscrYApHiQkUF27LVp4X1-W5wNIpDMNUEjPBDTsQw2zeC1+cF67hdp2MbXjXTF2yqSM2aVpfVzab5OTZR+LLCsGPSBtyCbFtXY7LsA42PsB2HUc-tcBPv27P8lxXU82a3Czd33HJj1Pc9L2c1iPUFUcAog41C-I5uTFjtJgML8CmEg6DYOH+Ce+4ij2PQquTGw3D8Ln9ZiNHMji57pBg5ouiP1Ap1J+XlC0M45iELk9Y++AwphMoiAxIkrfoHTWSTejpBHqKcONO67SN42OqEAjImTMlXXqgCjJw2AE3HibkSAeQED5N+7ozbBXymdNSOU1obQwaQHaaVMoBVQXlcKuCirrFMM7VssIOwWlho5YAFUYbNVavAiaU0MR7XvgdEKR0TrAlwRdIWUA7q5RwU9PEL1EEKSJlQVAxNfrfX+twwGvBgaIjBkgCGUMQpMK+PQkajCEb4EBEAA)