# Can I use Typescript mapped types to "flatten" or "unflatten" an object type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say we have a type with some nested properties, like so:

```js
type Deep = {
    foo: number;
    bar: {
        nested1: string;
        nested2: number[];
    }
}
```

But we need to pass objects of that type through a system which can't handle nested properties. So we'll flatten the objects, using a separator like `_` to denote nested properties:

```js
type Flat = {
    foo: number;
    bar_nested1: string;
    bar_nested2: number[];
}
```

We can implement functions for flattening and unflattening these objects. But, if we want the functions to be generic, **how do we represent their return types?**. Is it even possible in Typescript currently (v4.5)?

```js
function flatten<TDeep>(deep: TDeep): Flatten<TDeep>; // How do we define `Flatten<>`?
function unflatten<TFlat>(flat: TFlat): Unflatten<TFlat>; // How do we define `Unflatten<>`?
```

I had a stab at `Unflatten<>` using Typescript 4.5.

```js
type Unflatten<T> = WithoutDeepProps<T> & WithUnflattenedProps<T>

type WithoutDeepProps<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T as Exclude<Property, `${string}_${string}`>]: T[Property];
}

type WithUnflattenedProps<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T as ParentOf<Property>]: {
        [ChildProperty in ChildOf<Property>]: T[Property]
    }
}

type ParentOf<T> = T extends `${infer Parent}_${string}` ? Parent : never;
type ChildOf<T> = T extends `${string}_${infer Child}` ? Child : never;
```

This kind-of works but it unions the nested property types. So, using `Flat` from above:

```js
// Unflatten<Flat> gives:
foo: number;
bar: {
    nested1: string | number[];
    nested2: string | number[];
}
```

I haven't even tried `Flatten<>` because I don't know how I would convert one property (e.g. `bar`) into many (`bar_nested1`, `bar_nested2`)

Comment: When flattening, you are going to run into the issue of potential key duplication (e.g. the combination of parent_child key already exists as a sibling of parent).

Comment: Likewise, unflatten has to assume no underscores in property names to work reliably.

Comment: There's all kinds of caveats with such flattening (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620803/2887218 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111325/2887218 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923825/2887218) since it's not clear what you expect to see with index signatures, unions, optional properties, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first part would be to understand why you get that union there. It appears that when mapping, if the `as` clause produces duplicate properties (as it would here, as `bar_nested1` and `bar_nested1` end up being mapped to the same property `bar`) typescript will call the property type expression of the mapped type not with each individual key, but rather with their union. (So `Property` will be `bar_nested1` | `bar_nested1`). So when you index `T[Property]` you get a union of both types.

We can demonstrate this using this type:

```
type WithUnflattenedProps<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T as ParentOf<Property>]: [Property]
}

type Y = Id<WithUnflattenedProps<Flat>>
// Will be 
// type Y = {
//     bar: ["bar_nested1" | "bar_nested2"];
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=40&pln=32&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFigXigbwFBS1AZgezwC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG5NsqBDW4jbL0iAZ2AgATAIzF+tAJYkA5o27YSfAYIBMxctToBtALpzsAX3RH0oSFABiAGxbBkaJlnxFSlGg0dRWtAPqL+QqJQ4lKynt5+SkJqrpq0uowmZtAAqiQ4NsACJAA8ACoAfPYA6hLAABZ4ZMBwCAAKtHhgvPlFAGRQpRVpGbbZQg1NLYXopuDQXZXVtWCDza32nNhac3SgUFJQANYQIHg4UHlQLLxQAKIAHgDGVmSCEDmrtKAANFAABgAkqCEyBj7fX7SAzvAo6Yh5FaNSDPEB6YyjZKdMrlHqZfqCObDIooJZYKFNNYgDYkba7faHY6nOpsCAkYAAeRwj2hRLBxCgBJhoB0CLG5hptDpjOZhXsRwgF2yglOX1QUhwdCgguF-0BwEkf3eUAA-MrafSoOoIAA3OiMJEAYXKEisgiZCxQEqldJlH3VmuBAPl6SV1ttghBuqg-rtRp4Zo8-OgAElBI60AYoB0lisSWS9gc8uDDiteUlxlAAJr2OM5SZovp0gbQlrWWwFApAA)

We can fix this by rebuilding each property based on `ChildProperty` instead of using `Property`:

```
type WithUnflattenedProps<T> = {
    [Property in keyof T as ParentOf<Property>]: {
      [ChildProperty in ChildOf<Property>]:  T[`${ParentOf<Property>}_${ChildProperty }` & keyof T]
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-u8oAB+b1K+lQdQQABudEYSO14uZ9pQjuddNdH0BAdCfo9XqT+rDSajPDjHjG5gAkoIFriDAaHPi6sKjRTTRCVmbLeYABr2Ws5NF9Ok5ay2IoFIA)

You could also apply the type recursively to get unflatten a deeper hierarchy [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2FAvFA3gKCjqAzAewIC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwG5tcaF6B9MiAZ2AgAmARlJ96ASzIBzZrihtO3PoIBMpSrQYBtALqzW7Lr34CAzBwFl11OvV36cCo8rMWyaqGMlT7mAL6YmKCQUACqZHiIwPxkADwAKgB8qOh+UABkOFhyWgAK9ASQ9KBQklAA1hAgBHhQ8VAIPFAAogAeAMZwFAIQsfmFDKAANFAABgAk6F7SfhyT01J+o4k6pPF5BUWgev4ZGCw4GwPFIKVkFVU1dQ1NuewQZMAA8nh9m4MgK6RQAJICseFIkgYrFsnIoFoAMIAC3EcAE-S2pzKMLhAheb2OoC+OHWE3Qd3oD2er0RH0Ss0mqPhZJOUCWe0q1Vq8R0B3piUS-kCwWghOJGKSqGuEFaMQETXxkjwDCg-MelKmwAkM1GUAA-HL7o8oOoIAA3BjMXlQano15CtD1UXiyXzZXeRXS2Vmhmas268gGo088DQP4JZJoVJ7MF5M4XZl1VZ1PJsgJBP1QACawsBURB8CQiSAA)