# Typescript Type Flatten Child nested objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, flatten, infinite-recursion

i have been following this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCAoUSFABi7LsGARCMLgji4APABUAfFBwBvANoBpKAkJQA1hBAsAZlEUBdAFyWdVqBAAeEwgBNcsRCjSYoAPxQOgA09tpWjnYiYm7SsgqKDsoAvprGphbWUABkwfAskHCg2iZh8MioGBBW-ODQMeKSSqoamjB6Bo1xMnItUFxeMJoADJF2wwCMVim8vPoScGZcAMbQihD4AJKEi8trUOq8UJRcSBB2+ESkx5SbEu52RycnovgAcmcXeAT6Ny93fAQR6HW4ArjEb7UOgMMFQWYnWazXgAehRhwhUJo9DgYTewE+50uvxIYUIX2J11mAnW9zUwlETUISnuOz2qwgyl4QA)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919016/how-can-an-object-type-with-nested-subproperties-be-flattened)  to flatten a type invain.  Most of this flatten the object completely into  removing the nests. I would like to to maintain my structure, just removing some wrappers (in this case body) in the nested objected which can be anything and n deep.

I would like to transform my type from

```
type TestInterface {
  id: string
  body: {
    title: string 
    something: string 
    user: {
      id: string
      body: {
        firstname: string
        lastname: string
        age: number
      }
    }
    country: {
      id: string
      body: {
        code: string
        name: string
        region: {
          id: string
          body: {
            code: string
            name: string
            continent: {
              id: string
              body: {
               code: string
               name: string
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the required output is the same type structure above but with the body wrapper dropped.

```
type TestInterface {
  id: string
  title: string 
  something: string 
  user: {
    id: string
    firstname: string
    lastname: string
    age: number
  }
  country: {
    id: string
    code: string
    name: string
    region: {
      id: string
      code: string
      name: string
      continent: {
        id: string
        code: string
        name: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Pure<T> = T extends object ? {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} : T
type Flatten<T> = Pure<
| T extends {body: any} ? Flatten2<Omit<T, 'body'> & T['body']> : Flatten2<T>
>
type Flatten2<T> = T extends object ? {[K in keyof T]: Flatten<T[K]>} : T

type X = Flatten<TestInterface>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=32&pln=38&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCSA7YEBOAzAhgY2gF4oBvAWACgooBLAEwC4pEMaUBzS6gIwHs6QTclWpQUOALYQmLNuyhdRAGxyIAcpOnNgrDgpHUArvExDFo2o227OB0XwFm7FrDQyJxUmTrnmLUFQ9Nbxs-Cxx2LRRDCW5MMKgAXz9kuzxeQzQMQVIE%20hDfZygHHOF-UXS6LVkOBOpPap9aouoMCHYaXhQncot860Le%2035Suv9KxtCW-waC5qGLdLQ2CDQehb6rGtsNixL13eoJuZ3D%20uCB%20bPUw5uFu-KH0Se71NTKUEgoAAVDNoAeGAAPigxBgUAgAA90Cg6PAoLxuAArCB4YBQAD8pAA2gBpWgoKAAawgIF4WFgAF0mDA8ZTElAaR9wNAAGIqYAwwEg4i-AGUAA%20sAh0NWcNI%20ygOBQIAZWPZOE5qwATP8APISGjAQEAGigAHISvqQQAyWDYw0jfWUkFMBVKlCq4GUIHMr72mFOnnCqEw8WIlFozE4-FsYmk8lUu0crm03E2hlMihu6AADVBUA9q0BCGQaEwuAIrooAHoS6IAHoYyg15N12sNihAA)

Comment: thanks @Dimava. this works appreciated

Comment: i am extending this to a generic it kind looses the types.  see line 68 - 74 that organization can not be reached. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQkBw)